# Executing simple aliased shell command without opening terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I often have to reconfigure my monitors for work, home, etc. on my laptop running 18.04. I wrote a simple shell aliased command in my `.bashrc` that configures them for the location (eg. `wmc` for "work monitor config").

Currently I open a terminal and execute the command, but it would be nicer to just hit a key (like the windows key) and type `wmc` without having to open the terminal and execute it.

How can I execute my aliased command without opening a terminal?

Comment: Doesn't creating a keyboard shortcut with the same command for `wmc` work?

Comment: @pomsky Yeah. I was hoping executing the little command would be easier, but either way

Comment: ...or create desktop entries that show up when you hit the windows key and type `wmc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways that might work for you.
Both involve using the shortcut `ALT + F2`, which opens a "Run Command" prompt.

1. <s>Enter your bash alias into the "Run Command" prompt, like so: `bash -c <alias>`.</s>
2. Export your alias code as a script, make it executable, put it into your PATH and run it with `<alias>` from the "Run Command" prompt.

Regarding solution 2, it is not really the alias that will be called but a script that has the same code as the alias. It could work like this:

Put a file with the name of your alias into the `~/.local/bin` folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
<code of your alias>
```

and make it executable with `chmod +x <file>`

Hopefully, that helped

**Update:**

I realized that aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shell. While it is possible to use `bash -ic <alias>` (thanks to @steeldriver) to run an alias in interactive shell, this is **NOT** recommended, as the shell does not close after the command and stays open, which takes up processing power.

I would recommend solution 2 instead.

Comment: Does `bash -c <alias>` really work? I'd expect it to run a non-interactive shell (in which aliases are disabled by default). `bash -ic <alias>` might work though.

Comment: It seems you are right. `bash -ic <alias>` works, but then it stays open and takes up a lot of processing power (had to kill those processes manually)...So that does not seem like a good solution either...Any ideas?

Comment: Your script solution is how I'd do it (possibly with a keyboard shortcut to execute the script) - I don't see any value in trying to kludge it to work through an alias

Comment: I got the script to work from the command prompt (and could even assign a CTRL+ALT+SPACE hotkey to it), but only by writing the full path: `sh "/home/me/local/bin/my-script"`. Neither the `$PATH` variable, nor an alias, nor `~` was understood.